# Remove minutes from datetime - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @MinutesToAdd int = 20; 
DECLARE @StartTimeDate datetime = '2017-06-05 14:37:56.113';  
DATEADD(minute,@MinutesToAdd,@StartTimeDate);
```

Code above adds 20 minutes to StartTimeDate. Is there a good way to remove those 20 minutes not add? Tried to find a solution, but didn't catch one. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the DBMS tag

Comment: try passing -20

Comment: Added sql server tag based on the syntax used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any specific function to subtract any dateparts

Just add negative symbol in front

```
Select DATEADD(minute,-@MinutesToAdd,@StartTimeDate);
```

or multiply with -1

```
Select DATEADD(minute,@MinutesToAdd * -1 ,@StartTimeDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @MinutesToAdd int = -20; 
    DECLARE @StartTimeDate datetime = '2017-06-05 14:37:56.113';  
    select DATEADD(minute,@MinutesToAdd,@StartTimeDate);
```